# keras face recognition accuracy not going above 50%

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm pretty new to deep learning and i'm trying to make a face recognizer for anime faces. This is my current code

CNN

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, padding='same', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
return model
```

Training CNN

```py
def run():
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = datasets.load_data(img_rows=32, img_cols=32)

    Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
    Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

    model = CNN(input_shape=X_train.shape[1:], nb_classes=nb_classes)
    csv_logger = CSVLogger('../log/cnn.log')

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

    X_test = preprocess_input(X_test)

    checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="../resources/weights.hdf5", monitor="val_accuracy", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False, 
        samplewise_center=False,  
        featurewise_std_normalization=False, 
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  
        zca_whitening=False,  
        rotation_range=0,  
        width_shift_range=0.1,  
        height_shift_range=0.1, 
        horizontal_flip=True,  
        vertical_flip=False , 
        preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
    ) 

    datagen.fit(X_train)
    
    history = model.fit(
        datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
            steps_per_epoch= round(X_train.shape[0] / batch_size),
            epochs=nb_epoch,
            validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), 
            callbacks=[csv_logger, checkpointer], batch_size=batch_size
    )
```

With this I don't go above 50% accuracy sometimes not even 10%

When i change the CNN to this, the accuracy goes to 65% and doesn't increase further

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, padding='same', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='sigmoid')
return model
```

How would i improve this to get atleast 90% accuracy

---

**More Info over the Model**

```
nb_epoch = 200
batch size = 10
nb_classes = 83
```

The dataset in total has around 3000 files.

Comment: Hi @skrx10, welcome to the community. Well, it seems like there could be only too many reasons. For example, why did you prefer _sigmoid_ and _rmsprop_? Are you following a tutorial perhaps? The reason could also be solely that you are not training your network enough to reach higher values; what's the value of _nb_epoch_?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not providing enough information. I was using softmax at first but as i was going through similar problems on stackoverflow, a user had said to use sigmoid rather than softmax. As for the nb_epoch, its value is 200, batch size is 10 and nb_classes is 83. I tried using other optimizers instead of rmsprop but i seemed to get higher accuracy in rmsprop but yes i am following a tutorial

Comment: What is the size of the dataset? Also, are you generating your own one? Usually, some processing takes place before feeding it to the network. Perhaps that piece is missing. I see that 2nd network resulted better than the first one, but I'm not sure about the idea of dropping the Activation functions altogether. Have you tried any pre-trained networks, e.g. resnet, vgg, btw?

Comment: The dataset in total has around 3000 files. Yes I'm generating my own and all the processing is pretty much done. I haven't tried any pre-trained models